# How can I check if upstart is installed in ubuntu server and how can I install it?

Tags: installation, upstart

I want to install upstart to my ubuntu server 13.10, but I am confused if I need to download the source or install package. In [upstart's getting started page](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) I think they instruct to install the source.

But [here](http://geeknme.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/getting-started-with-upstart-in-ubuntu/) and [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart) they seem to say that upstart is included with later distributions. I tried `initctl` in the shell and I got missing command error. Does this mean I need to install it from source? I am new to ubuntu so I would appreciate if you can explain how I can install upstart.

Comment: A "typical user" should not even bother with that kind of stuff. What are you trying to do? What is _the real problem_?

Comment: I am trying to follow the instructions here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/lnGvHyRzX7w/N8eDnwJPXuAJ to start and stop the server with an upstart job.

Comment: Please open a specific question for that. As you see in my answer, Upstart is certainly present on your machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do have upstart installed. In fact, the [webpage you linked](http://geeknme.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/getting-started-with-upstart-in-ubuntu/) reads: `Ubuntu has had upstart installed as a replacement for init scripts since as far back as 2006, but it hasn’t yet been really used until the latest beta release of Karmic (Ubuntu 9.10).` and [Upstart home page](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) lists Ubuntu 6.10 and later as using Upstart.

To learn `initctl` usage, type `initctl --help` or `man initctl`.

The message

```
user@ubuntu:~$ initctl
initctl: missing command
Try `initctl --help' for more information.
```

is printed by `initctl` and implies that it is installed and executable, otherwise the shell would rather print `initctl: command not found`. In fact, `which initctl` returns `/sbin/initctl` on my machine.

Comment: Great, thanks. I read the above quote but upstart page confused me. Thanks, for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

To check what version of upstart you are running:

```
initctl --version
```

Expect output similar to this:

```
initctl (upstart 1.5)
Copyright (C) 2012 Scott James Remnant, Canonical Ltd.

This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

To check what version of Ubuntu you are running:

```
lsb_release -sd
```

Expect output similar to this:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
```